# Sending array attribute of object to Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

(*sorry for my english*)

I have a little problem.

### Shop Bascket

I want to store at session a shop-bascket, so I created the `php/classes/bascket.php`:

```
class Product
{
    private $id;
    private $quantity;

    function __construct(int $id, int $q)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->quantity = $q;
    }

    ...
}

class Bascket
{
    private $products = array();

    /* for testing */
    function __construct()
    {
        $this->products[] = new Product(26, 1006);
    }

    function add(int $id, int $quantity)
    {
        ...
    }

    function delete(int $id, int $quantity)
    {
        ...
    }

    function __get($field) {
        return $this->$field;
    }
}
```

### Using the Shop Bascket

And I use this class on session anywhere I want:

```
include "php/classes/bascket.php"; (*or another correct path*)

session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION["bascket"])) {
    $_SESSION["bascket"] = serialize(new Bascket());
}
$bascket = unserialize($_SESSION["bascket"]);
```

### Trying to display Bascket Shop with Ajax

Because I want to show the bascket on pressing a button, I made an ajax which do the following thing:

```
function display_bascket() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'php/take_bascket.php',
        dataType: 'text',
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,                         
        type: 'post',
        success: function(bascket){
           //bascket = JSON.parse(bascket);
           //bascket = jQuery.parseJSON(bascket);
           $("#content").html(bascket);
        }
   });
}
```

And I tried a lot to can display the correct thing in `take_bascket.php` to receive a good array, or a json in ajax.

### take_bascket.php

```
<?php

session_start();

include "classes/bascket.php";

if(!isset($_SESSION["bascket"])) {
    $_SESSION["bascket"] = serialize(new Bascket());
}

// I tried many variants:


var_dump($_SESSION["bascket"]);
/*
 * output:
 * string(116) "O:3:"Bascket":1:{s:12:"Bascketproducts";a:1:{i:0;O:6:"Product":2:{s:10:"Productid";i:26;s:17:"Productquantity";i:1006;}}}"
 *
 * and I don't know how to handled it in ajax to get the products array
*/

var_dump(unserialize($_SESSION["bascket"]));
/*
 * output:
 * object(Bascket)#1 (1) { ["products":"Bascket":private]=> array(1) { [0]=> object(Product)#2 (2) { ["id":"Product":private]=> int(26) ["quantity":"Product":private]=> int(1006) } } }
 *
 * and I don't know how to handled it in ajax to get the products array
*/

var_dump(json_encode($_SESSION["bascket"]));
/*
 * output:
 * string(158) ""O:3:\"Cos\":1:{s:12:\"\u0000Cos\u0000products\";a:1:{i:0;O:6:\"Product\":2:{s:10:\"\u0000Product\u0000id\";i:26;s:17:\"\u0000Product\u0000quantity\";i:1006;}}}""
 *
 * and I don't know how to handled it in ajax to get the products array
*/

var_dump(((unserialize($_SESSION["bascket"]))->products));
/*
 * output:
 * array(1) { [0]=> object(Product)#2 (2) { ["id":"Product":private]=> int(26) ["quantity":"Product":private]=> int(1006) } }
 *
 * and I don't know how to handled it in ajax to get the products array
*/

var_dump(((unserialize($_SESSION["bascket"]))->products[0]));
/*
 * output:
 * object(Product)#2 (2) { ["id":"Product":private]=> int(26) ["quantity":"Product":private]=> int(1006) }
 *
 * and I don't know how to handled it in ajax to get the products array
*/
```

## Conclusion

As you can see I also tried different ways of manipulate the output in ajax. But or it is a string and I can't convert it in array. Or I can't make it json, etc.

## Please

Please, can you try find a complete solution? I mean for take_bascket.php, but also for what I have to do in display_bascket() in js.

thank you in advance

## *Edit*:

I did as someone said in a post:

`php/classes/bascket.php`

```
<?php

class Product
{
    private $id;
    private $quantity;

    function __construct(int $id, int $q)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->quantity = $q;
    }

    function decrease(int $value)
    {
        ...
    }

    function increase(int $value) {
        ...
    }

    public function toArray(){
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'quantity' => $this->quantity,
        ];
    }
}

class Bascket
{
    private $products = array();

    /* for testing */
    function __construct()
    {
        $this->products[] = new Product(26, 1006);
    }

    function add(int $id, int $quantity)
    {
        ...
    }

    function delete(int $id, int $quantity) 
    {
        ...
    }

    public function toJson(){
        $products = [];
        foreach ($this->products as $product) {
            $products[] = $product->toArray();
        }
        return json_encode(
            [
                'products' => $products
            ],
            JSON_PRETTY_PRINT
        );
    }

    function __get($field) {
        return $this->$field;
    }
}
```

And that's how I would theoretical create a PHP JSON easier.

But look at `take_bascket.php`:

```
<?php

session_start();

include "classes/bascket.php";

if(!isset($_SESSION["bascket"])) {
    $_SESSION["bascket"] = serialize(new Bascket());
}

var_dump(((unserialize($_SESSION["bascket"]))->toJson()));
/*
 * output:
 * string(98) "{ "products": [ { "id": 26, "quantity": 1006 } ] }" 
*/
```

## Trying to use it in `display_bascket()`:

```
function display_bascket() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'php/take_bascket.php',
        dataType: 'text',
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,                         
        type: 'post',
        success: function(bascket){
           //bascket = JSON.parse(bascket);
           $("#content").html(bascket);
        }
   });
}
```

If I don't use `JSON.parse()`, it'll display the next plain text:
string(98) "{ "products": [ { "id": 26, "quantity": 1006 } ] }"
Instead, if I use JSON.parse(), I have a console error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token s in JSON at position 0 
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)at Object.success (display_bascket.js:10) 
at j (jquery.js:2) at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js:2) 
at x (jquery.js:4) at XMLHttpRequest.b (jquery.js:4)
```

## What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that in each object you create a method that will return a JSON representation of that object.

For instance (filename: products.php):

```
class Product {

    private $name;
    private $value;
    private $quantity;

    public function __construct($name, $value, $quantity){
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->value = $value;
        $this->quantity = $quantity;
    }

    public function toArray(){
        return [
            'name' => $this->name,
            'value' => $this->value,
            'quantity' => $this->quantity,
        ];
    }
}

class Basket{

    private $products = [];

    public function addProduct(Product $p){
        $this->products[] = $p; 
    }
    public function toJson(){
        $products = [];
        foreach ($this->products as $p) {
            $products[] = $p->toArray();
        }
        return json_encode(
            [
                'products' => $products
            ],
            JSON_PRETTY_PRINT
        );
    }
}

$b = new Basket();

$b->addProduct(new Product('Apple', 1, 5));
$b->addProduct(new Product('Banana', .5, 2));
$b->addProduct(new Product('Carrots', .35, 6));

echo $b->toJson();
```

This will generate a JSON object that you can use with jQuery `.getJSON()` method.

Like the example below (filename: products.html):

```
<html>
    <head>

        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"> </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h3>Product list</h3>
    </body>
    <script>
        $(function(){
            $.getJSON( "products.php", function( data ) {
                console.log(data);
                var items = [];
                $.each( data.products, function( key, val ) {
                  items.push( "<li>Name: " + val.name + " | Quantity: " + val.quantity + " | Price: " + val.value + "</li>" );
                });

                $( "<ul/>", {
                  html: items.join( "" )
                }).appendTo( "body" );
            });
        });
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: Ok. But can you also please write the js part? Cause I can't for myself :(

Comment: I did it finally. Thanks Paulo.